# What is the whole goal of stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

What are the main goals of stackexchange.com?

Comment: To provide a better resource than our dashed friends?

Comment: To make the internet better

Comment: Is it really *that* difficult to go to stackexchange.com, and look through the FAQ?

Comment: @Pekka Link? I can't find it.

Comment: @C.Ross heh :) To be fair though, SE.com's "about" section *does* link to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Pekka to the [Management page](http://stackoverflow.com/about/management), which tells you *who* not *why*.

Comment: 3rd paragraph from the bottom of [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-gives-back-2010/)

Comment: @C.Ross the "mission" tab isn't far, though. But it isn't SE specific, admittedly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [blog says](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/more-trilogy-sites/):

> One thing we’ve been pitching a lot to
> VCs is our love for internet
> communities that are obsessive about
> something, where that something could
> be … well, anything, really. I feel
> that the kind of expert communities
> that arise around a shared passion for
> something are not only fascinating but
> help the world at large, in that these
> experts produce a lot of highly
> relevant content that any average
> person can dip their toes in when they
> need advice about that particular
> topic.
>
> Our goal with the Stack Overflow
> engine, then, is to unlock this
> content and release expert communities
> from the Soviet-era phpBB and
> vBulletin software they’ve been
> trapped in for so many years. In other
> words, better living through software!

Answer (score 0):

The main goal is to provide an infrastructure to have Question & Answers sites in different topics, where community asks and answers the questions. Allowing fast feedback between the users. It is also community managed! :)